# PostCSS plugin: how to get a value of CSS4 variable

Tags: javascript, build, postcss, css-variables

I use [svg-transform-loader](https://github.com/JetBrains/svg-mixer/tree/master/packages/svg-transform-loader) together with [postcss-move-props-to-bg-image-query](https://github.com/JetBrains/svg-mixer/tree/master/packages/postcss-move-props-to-bg-image-query) in order to modify SVG properties via postCSS.

I don't use `postcss-css-variables` plugin so my CSS variables are not converted into pure strings - they remain in the code as they are.

It needs to be like this because I don't want to pass the whole CSS code through `postcss-css-variables`, but I'd like to use `postcss-css-variables` as a standalone tool to parse only some specific variables within the `transform` callback of the `postcss-move-props-to-bg-image-query` PostCSS plugin.

I'd like to be able to do:

```css
:root {
  --my-css-variable: blue;
}

.img {
  background-image: url('./img.svg');
  -svg-mixer-fill: var(--my-css-variable); // I need `var(--my-css-variable)` to be converted to `blue`
}
```

When I pass that code through the `postcss-move-props-to-bg-image-query`  plugin then `var(--my-css-variable)` is not evaluated - I'd like to use `postcss-css-variables/lib/resolve-value` module to get the value of this variable.

I already forked the `postcss-move-props-to-bg-image-query` in a way that in the `transform` callback I have access to `root` and `declaration` PostCSS objects.

```js
const resolveValue = require('postcss-css-variables/lib/resolve-value');
const moveProps = require('postcss-move-props-to-bg-image-query');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    moveProps({
      transform: ({ name, value }, root, declaration) => {
        // `name` is '-svg-mixer-fill'
        // `value` is `var(--my-css-variable)`. I'd like to convert it to `blue`

        const map = {
          // I don't know how to use `name` and `value` to create the properly structured object.
        };
        const evaluatedCssVariable = resolveValue(declaration, map); // I'd like it to return `blue`

        return {
          name: name.replace(/^-svg-mixer-/, ''),
          value: evaluatedCssVariable,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

And now I'm stuck. I don't know how to use the `resolveValue()` module. I know that it takse `declaration` as a first argument and `map` object as second argument, but I have no idea how to build a proper `map` object.

I don't necessarily need to use `postcss-css-variables/lib/resolve-value` - I just thought that I could use it to extract the values of CSS4 variables because that's what this plugin does internally. I'm open to any alternatives.